# Slidedown jumping problem on hidden submenu

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I have made a jQuery/css submenu, seen on the left side of the page below:

http://borviz.ro/exact-tours/inner.html

When the menu slides down, there is a jumping effect, which i cant figure out, why it is.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently its costly animating the inline-block on the `div.submenu > ul > li`
if you set this to `display:block` it’s a lot smoother